# How to run a series of functions, if one of them executes, return

Tags: ios, swift

I am initialising container view controllers in my prepareForSegue function like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    initialiseTopViewController(for: segue)
    initialiseMessagesViewController(for: segue)
    initialiseToolbarViewController(for: segue)
    initialiseTicketViewController(for: segue)
}
```

Only one of these functions will actually run per segue due to `guard` conditions on the segue identifier. How can I make it so that if one of these functions executes, it doesn't continue trying to execute the others? Is there a better way than just using `if...else if` blocks

Comment: A `switch` (which is a if else/if) might be more readable though.

Comment: I think you'd better use a switch, because that's the very purpose of it:
"A switch statement considers a value and compares it against several possible matching patterns. It then executes an appropriate block of code, based on the first pattern that matches successfully."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @rob mayoff's suggestion, have each function return a `Bool` and loop through an array that holds all of them, making this completely data-driven.

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   let funs = [ initialiseTopViewController(for:), 
                initialiseMessagesViewController(for:), 
                initialiseToolbarViewController(for:), 
                initialiseTicketViewController(for:) ]

   for fun in funs {
       if fun(segue) {
           break
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to make each `initialise` function return `true` if it handles the segue, else `false`. Then:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    _ = (false
        || initialiseTopViewController(for: segue)
        || initialiseMessagesViewController(for: segue)
        || initialiseToolbarViewController(for: segue)
        || initialiseTicketViewController(for: segue)
    )
}

private func initialiseTopViewController(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue) -> Bool { ... }
private func initialiseMessagesViewController(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue) -> Bool { ... }
private func initialiseToolbarViewController(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue) -> Bool { ... }
private func initialiseTicketViewController(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue) -> Bool { ... }
```

Another solution is to hoist the appropriate tests up into `prepare(for:sender:)`, for example using a `switch`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch (segue.identifier ?? "", segue.destination) {
        case (_, let dest as TopViewController): initialiseTopViewController(dest)
        case (_, let dest as MessagesViewController): initialiseMessagesViewController(dest)
        case ("toolbar", let dest as MultipurposeViewController): initialiseToolbarViewController(dest)
        case ("ticket", let dest as MultipurposeViewController): initialiseTicketViewController(dest)
        default: super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    }
}

private func initialiseTopViewController(_ controller: TopViewController) { ... }
private func initialiseMessagesViewController(_ controller: MessagesViewController) { ... }
private func initialiseToolbarViewController(_ controller: MultipurposeViewController) { ... }
private func initialiseTicketViewController(_ controller: MultipurposeViewController) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a `switch` statement that checks/casts `destination` for various types, and passing that typed value to the appropriate method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.destination {
    case let destination as FooViewController: prepare(destination)
    case let destination as BarViewController: prepare(destination)
    case let destination as BazViewController: prepare(destination)
    default: super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    }
}

func prepare(_ destination: FooViewController) {
    destination.foo = foo
}

func prepare(_ destination: BarViewController) {
    destination.bar = bar
}

func prepare(_ destination: BazViewController) {
    destination.baz = baz
}
```

This `switch` only calls the appropriate method and saves those separate methods from needing to do any `guard` statements at all.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to @rob mayoff's solution with making the functions return `bool`

```
// make each function return boolean values so you know if it executed properly or not based on the return value
func initialiseTopViewController(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue) -> Bool { ... }
func initialiseMessagesViewController(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue) -> Bool { ... }
func initialiseToolbarViewController(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue) -> Bool { ... }
func initialiseTicketViewController(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue) -> Bool { ... }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // if any function returns true, then return and don't run the remaining functions
    if initialiseTopViewController(for: segue) { return }
    if initialiseMessagesViewController(for: segue) { return }
    if initialiseToolbarViewController(for: segue) {return }
    if initialiseTicketViewController(for: segue) { return }
}
```

I'm sorry if this is similar to other suggestions. I just wanted to show you how to do achieve easily with in-line if statements.